# Moving All Files From Directories One Step Up

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, mv

I have a directories that look like this

```
fool@brat:/mydir/ucsc_mm8> tar -xvf *.tar 
1/chr1.fa.masked
1/chr1_random.fa.masked
2/chr2.fa.masked
3/chr3.fa.masked
4/chr4.fa.masked
5/chr5.fa.masked
5/chr5_random.fa.masked
19/chr19.fa.masked
Un/chrUn_random.fa.masked
```

What I want to do is to move out all the "*.masked" files in the subdirectories `/1` upto `/Un`.
Is there a compact way to do it in Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The typical way of moving files all files matching a particular expression is

```
mv 1/*.masked targetDir
```

where targetDir could be ..

If you want to move it from directories 1,2,3 then you can do something like

```
mv */*.masked targetDir
```

Or, if you want to specifically move it from numbered directories, you can just run something like

```
mv [0-9][0-9]/*.masked targetDir
```

Comment: The target directory of `..` will move files one step above the current working directory. Not what the OP wants. They want to move it one step above with respect to the actual source files.

Answer (score 6):

```
mv */*.masked .
```

Answer (score 5):

Many unix shells support the * operator in the directory portion of the path as well.  The following works in at least bash and zsh:

```
ls */*.masked
```

This will return all of the files that end in .masked one directory deeper.

So to move them:

```
mv */*.masked destination
```